# How to get this code to have a key value without creating a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm wrapping my head around OOP with PHP and getting a pretty good hold on it but I have this code that I just don't feel right to me and I need some help. Most of the code is from a tutorial on building a log-in system. The code provided in the tutorial presents errors at the top of an html page. I thought it would be more user friendly to have the errors presented next to the form field where the error occurs so I wrote additional code that works but it seems to heavy. I'd like some suggestions on how to lighten it up.
The class is named Validation and it's methods are called from the registration form. 
I don't know if you need the entire class posted so I'll post sections I'm working with.
Here are the methods that create an error array.

```
private function addError($error)
{
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function errors()
{
    return $this->_errors;
}
```

Here is just one line of error code that populates the array what was presenting the error at the top of the page. Within this block the `$item` within the `addError()` method call is the field name that produced the error.

```
if($rule === 'required' && empty($value))
{
    $this->addError("$item field is required."));                   
}
```

Here is how I changed the code so I could get the `$item` value to be place in the array. However this creates a mutlidimensional array that I have to loop through several layers to get to the key of `$item`.

```
if($rule === 'required' && empty($value))
{
    $this->addError(array($item=>"This field is required.")); //item is going to equal field name you can change this in the registration file
}
```

Here is the method I wrote to loop through the array and is what I am not liking.

```
public function frm_errors($item)
{   
    $errors = array($this->errors());

    foreach($errors as $error => $error_value)
    { 
        foreach($error_value as $field_error => $field_error_values)
        {   
            foreach($field_error_values as $field_error_value => $value )
            {
                if(array_key_exists($item, $field_error_values))
                {
                    echo $value;
                }
            }   
        }               
    }
}
```

Here is the method call from the registration form.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo Input::get('username'); ?>" autocomplete="off"><br />
<?php echo "<p class='error'>" . $validation->frm_errors('username') . "</p>"; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what my array looks like with the field names added.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => This field is required.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => This field is required.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [password] => This field is required.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pwrd_again] => This field is required.
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => This field is required.
        )

)
```

And here is what it looks like with without capturing the $items with the addError method
call

```
Array
(
    [0] => username must contain at least 5 characters's.
    [1] => This field is required.
    [2] => This field is required.
    [3] => This field is required.
    [4] => This field is required.
)
```

Comment: If you want `$item` to be used as the key, then just pass `$item` and the message as _two_ parameters to `addError`, and use `$this->_errors[$item] = $message;` in there. (Be aware though that this will overwrite all previous error messages for an item, if there could be more than one for an item.)

Comment: Yes there could be more than one error. Some $items are unique and have a min/max value.

Comment: Well then make `$this->_errors[$item]` an array, that you add new messages through, so that you can loop through the messages for each item later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the parameter $item is the name of the field that may have error messages.

if you var_dump($this->errors()); you will see what the array actually looks like. You will then see how to access the required field values.

What you asked for. ;-/

I am not being awkward. I just now realised that i had gotten involved in 'the programming', which i find fun, and what you actually wanted - which was the replacement for you original routine. That it looks so simple is due to the work you did! Your work showing the arrays etc. help a lot.

```
    public function frm_errors($item)
    {
        // $errorsFound = false;
        $errors = $this->errors(); // this is already an array.

        foreach($errors as $value)
        {
           if (key($value) == $item) {
             // $errorsFound = true;
             // echo key($value);     // fieldname
             echo current($value); // error message
           }
        }
        // return $errorsFound;
    }
```

In the simplest form:

```
    public function frm_errors($item)
    {
        foreach($this->errors() as $value) // $value is an array of: $fieldName => $message
        {
           if (key($value) == $item) { // required field? 
             echo current($value);     // error message
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited my original post with the array structure of both outputs.

Comment: I know this may sound stupid or naive but this code is in a class that is supposed to be abstract so If I put the field names directly here I can't use this class on other forms. Is that not correct?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear - the function i have indicated above is just a replacement for your function! copy and paste it and it should just work. Forget about everything else.

Comment: Perfect! I knew that code could be trimmed down. I'll study it and learn from it.